# Error on runtime for library containing javax.security in it

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am running Android Studio project with some libraries. And one of the library causes error on compile.

That library contains "javax.security" package in it, and I think that package is causing issues.
[image]

And here is the error message on compile,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

Are there possible solutions for this issue?

And is it not allowed to use libraries having javax package in it?

Thank you for help